# JQuery Regex Validation for non zero and non decimal numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation, jquery-plugins

Currently I am using a perfect method for decimal validation:

```
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur", function (event) {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d].+/, ""));
     if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

Now I Need a method which can allow me to insert digits from from 1-10000, and don't allow anybody to insert 0 at first place, but any one can put zero on second or third place and also I don't want decimal

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust your regex to check for everything that's not a digit or 0 just on the first place of your value and additionally discard everything that's not a number like this:

```
$(".allownumericwithoutdecimal").on("keypress keyup blur", function (event) {
     $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/^([^\d]|0)[^\d].+|[^\d].+/, ""));
     if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
         event.preventDefault();
     }
 });
```

Comment: it is working fine for alphabets and decimal point but not working for leading 0